# SQL: How to update a Composite Key?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

In the UI, i am showing `account_id` and `account_name`.
The user is able to update the account_id as well as account_name and the account_id is unique for the user.  Since I am allowing the user to update the account_id (composite key) how can I create a where clause while doing update?

Below is my table design.

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
  user_id      VARCHAR2(20)  NOT NULL,
  account_id   VARCHAR2(20)  NOT NULL, 
  account_name VARCHAR2(20)  NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE accounts ADD CONSTRAINT
uk_myTable_1 UNIQUE (User_id, account_id)
```

Comment: While this works I'm all for an immutable key behind the scenes that I never share or display; it eliminates problems with foreign key relationships and updates to parts of composite keys.  (IE add a field (AccountID which is the PK, and used in FK relationships.

Comment: @OMGPonies Its Oracle...

Comment: Some fodder for thought: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8187/should-a-primary-key-be-immutable

Comment: Ah ORACLE, there's a concept there called ORA_ROWSCN when used in combination with  row dependencies when you create a table that assigns a unique ID to each row in a table and that value changes any time an update is done to the row.  Kinda saves you in a multi-user environment from writing over eachother.  the combination of those two elements gives you the tools to make the update you want.  Row Dependencies is optional if you know you don't ahve a multi-user environment and stateless UI to contend with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `account_id` and `user_id` values remain until you change them.

Thus. if it starts out as `user_id` 10 with `account_id` 20 and you change `account_id` to 30 e.g.

```
 UPDATE accounts 
    SET account_id = '30' 
  WHERE account_id = '20'
        AND user_id = '10';
```

While the above works for situations where you retain all values of your composite key,  I'm all for an immutable key behind the scenes that is never shared or displayed.  It eliminates problems with foreign key relationships and updates to parts of composite keys. To implement this, add a field (AccountID) which is the PK, and used in FK relationships.

Alternatively, Oracle can do something similar to this by using ROWSCN and in stateless environments rowdependencies on all tables.  The problem you can run into with use if just AccountID is that its possible, in a multi user environment, to have person a make update to record 1 and user 2 to be editing record 1 and then save; overwriting user 1's updates.    For this is the reason I mentioned ROWSCN and ROWDEPENDENCIES.  However, if you are in a state aware environment, this would be overkill.

Lastly, you could change the order of operations to execute the update to the database BEFORE you update your class.  This way you have both values.

Comment: I like your solution of having immutable key behind the scenes... Make your point clear on your answer section...

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE accounts
SET whatevercolumnsyouwantasnormal
WHERE USER_ID = 'whatever' and ACCOUNT_ID = 'whatever2'
```

Obviously this will require you to track the original USER_ID and ACCOUNT_ID (separately from the new ones) until you issue the UPDATE.

If this is a web app (in particular), be sure to consider the case where the user triggers this process twice in quick succession.

**Alternatively, look into Oracle's [RowID](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm). You could use it in the WHERE clause instead of the PK columns.**

Comment: update accounts set account_id=’dummy2’ where user_id='user1' and account_id='accountid'. Since i change the account_id in the UI, in the business layer i don't have old account_id to form a where clause...

Comment: Hidden fields in a GUI, to track the composite key. or your class needs to be extended to retain the values of the composite key so you can build the where clause...

Comment: @james007 You will need to track a way to identify the row somehow. There is no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE accounts SET account_id = New_account,account_name = new_name
WHERE user_id = Old_id and account_id = old_account_id
```

Comment: Since i am changing the account_id, i don't maintain the old_account_id.. I am flexiable enough to change the table design if needed.... Do i need to keep track of old_values?I believe that not the good practive..

Comment: You must have the original account ID stored somewhere, else how would you find the record.   I am only suggesting using the old account ID for a search key...

Comment: I think he means the class containing the information is overwritten BEFORE he does the DB update.  Alternative option would be to do the UPDATE to the database BEFORE you update the class.

Answer (score 0):

The unit of work in SQL is the row, not the column.

Now don't actually run this but **consider that**:

```
UPDATE accounts 
   SET user_id = account_id, 
       account_id = user_id ;
```

would successfully swap `user_id` and `account_id` for all users. This is because all rows affected by the update (as determined by the `WHERE` clause) are updated all at once.